# How to change IP in Postgresql jira databse

Tags: postgresql, jira

I have a server on which I have installed Jira application. Now we have changed the IP schema and since then  I am not able to access Jira. In `catalina.out` log I have found below error

```
2016-04-18 13:12:55,958 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR      [o.o.c.entity.jdbc.DatabaseUtil] Unable to establish a connection with the database... Error was:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2016-04-18 13:12:55,959 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR      [o.o.c.entity.jdbc.DatabaseUtil] Could not get table name information from the database, aborting.
2016-04-18 13:12:55,982 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR      [NoModule] Error getting datasource via DBCP: JdbcDatasourceInfo{uri='jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.228:5432/jira', driverClassName='org.postgresql.Driver', username='super', password='********', isolationLevel='null', connectionProperties=null, connectionPoolInfo=ConnectionPoolInfo{maxSize=20, minSize=20, initialSize=null, maxIdle=20, maxWait=30000, sleepTime=300000, lifeTime=600000, deadLockMaxWait=600000, deadLockRetryWait=10000, validationQuery=null, minEvictableTimeMillis=null, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=null, poolPreparedStatements=null, testOnBorrow=null, testOnReturn=null, testWhileIdle=null, maxOpenPreparedStatements=null, numTestsPerEvictionRun=null, removeAbandonedTimeout=300, validationQueryTimeout=null, defaultCatalog=null}}
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.atlassian.jira:name=BasicDataSource
```

Any idea where and how to change that IP?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/connecting-jira-to-postgresql-185729433.html

Comment: No dbconfig.xml on jira instance, is there any other way to change IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go into /opt/atlassian/jira/bin folder and run ./config.sh

There I entered proper details and then save the config.

This time dbconfig.xml file generated in /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/ folder.

And my issue resolved.